# Windows8 backgroundtask with async tasks (deferral)

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-8, windows-runtime, async-await

I want to update live tiles on Background Task winmd.

```vb
Public Async Sub Run(taskInstance As IBackgroundTaskInstance) Implements IBackgroundTask.Run
        Dim deferral As BackgroundTaskDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral()
        UpdateLiveTile()
        deferral.Complete()
End Sub

'and

Public Shared Async Sub UpdateLiveTile()
....
 await UpdateTileImage...something
End Sub
```

If I make the code like that, the Background task exits the process before `UpdateTileImage`.
It means that the `deferral.Complete()` is reached before doing the whole procedure.

Therefore, I tried to change UpdateLiveTile as a Async Task like:

```vb
Public Async Sub Run(taskInstance As IBackgroundTaskInstance) Implements IBackgroundTask.Run
        Dim deferral As BackgroundTaskDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral()
        Await UpdateLiveTile()
        deferral.Complete()
End Sub

' and

Public Shared Async Function UpdateLiveTile() as Task
....
End Function
```

But the compiler throws an error something like "changing method signature to use one of....." which probably tells that I cannot fire the function as a Task in Windows Runtime, not in a normal .Net framework.

> Actual error message : Method 'BackgroundTasks.NS.UpdateLiveTile()'
>   has a parameter of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' in its
>   signature.  Although this type is not a valid Windows Runtime type, it
>   implements interfaces that are valid Windows Runtime types.  Consider
>   changing the method signature to use one of the following types
>   instead: ''.  BackgroundTasks

[image: error position]
(it should be both Public and Shared function)

In summary, I just want to make sure the whole procedure can be done before calling deferral.Complete(). Thanks!

Comment: Please post the actual compiler error. Changing it to return Task is the correct solution.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary Posted an actual error message.

Comment: Try making the function `Private` instead.